# setting up icons for a list

Tags: android, icons, textview

I have an app in android that in some activity it displays using a item list the content from a column from the DB.

this is the way I'm doing it:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor,
                new String[] { db.KEY_USER }, new int[] { R.id.txt1 });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm using an adapter to connect the text view and the content of the table.

Here is how my Xml looks like"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/txt1"
  android:textSize="20dip" 
  android:padding="8dip" />
```

My question is:

How could I setup icons and colour for every list item that comes connected with my data from DB?

Comment: The `{}` icon in the toolbar above the edit field is marked **Code Layout** — you might want to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using [android.app.ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html). With a list activity you can provide an xml layout to create advanced visuals for your items.

Comment: So where is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that my items which come from DB are setup in a list view by an adapter so the icon must be set somehow using an image view that gets passed to the adapater...Have u ever tried this????I did what U said above...But what u said above is different from what I want!!!

Comment: Yes I have. You use a `<ImageView …>` with a dummy icon in your xml. In the `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` (or similar) you use `findById` to get the image and replace it with `setImageBitmap` to the `android.graphics.Bitmap` of your liking. — And BTW: it is **YOU** and not **U** on Stackoverflow. We are professional software developers and not script kiddies here.

Comment: Oh...forgive me...but I'm not that professional!Didn't mean to offend you in any way if that is what YOU understood:)